# Is there a way (or proposal) to return object when assigning to It, in JS?

Tags: javascript

I think, I saw it mentioned somewhere in past, but I cannot find It.
So, is there way to write
`myObject.x = 0, myObject` without comma operator?

I mainly use this with recucers:

```
const arr = [{key: 'width', value:15}, {key: 'height', value:30}]
const obj = arr.reduce((acc, {key, value}) => (acc[key] = value, acc), {})
```

I know, there is option to add a polyfill or function for that, but I'm looking for official solution (without spread `({...acc, [key]: value})`).

I could imagine something like pascal notation
`obj.x := 1`, or just make it behave like concatenation.

Maybe there is proposal for that?

Comment: Not that I know of. Also I think the use for this is very limited.

Comment: Btw: `Object.fromEntries(arr.map(it => [it.key, it.value]))`

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which takes a target and sources and returns the target.

```js
const
    arr = [{ key: 'width', value: 15 }, { key: 'height', value: 30 }],
    obj = arr.reduce(
        (acc, { key, value }) => Object.assign(acc, { [key]: value }),
        {}
    );

console.log(obj);
```

Proof of keeping the same object reference of `object.assign`.

```js
const
    arr = [{ key: 'width', value: 15 }, { key: 'height', value: 30 }],
    o = {},
    obj = arr.reduce(
        (acc, { key, value }) => Object.assign(acc, { [key]: value }),
        o
    );

console.log(o);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: But isn't it in efectivnes same as using Spread? Meaning, that it creates new object every time?

Comment: it keeps the same object reference. i add a proof by using an (outside) object as start value.

Comment: oh, okay, this is something I have failed to know, thank you for claryfying